# External HD format type and data loss

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have read that `ext4` is more reliable than `ntfs` in terms of possible dataloss. However I have also read that `ext4` 'uses' 5/7% of the available disk space so it can be assigned to the root user in case other users use up all the space on the drive.

I am willing to accept this loss of space (in the gigs) if it even slightly reduces the possibility of data loss (This includes my backups)

That said, I have no sources for these claims and cannot actually find that much information on the web about them. I have read about `btrfs` but I have come across many claims that it is still in relative infancy.

If I use linux, is `ext4` currently the 'best' option for formatting an external drive to prevent data loss?

Comment: I have never seen a hard drive that lost data where the loss was not by physical damage, i.e, the data was lost no matter what format was used. Is there any reliable data about NTFS (or any other file system) losing data?

Answer (score 0):

Ext4 is an excellent choice.  It is probably your best option if you are using USB with one external drive.

If multiple drives are an option and using esata check out ZFS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean Ext4 or the "fourth extended filesystem."

It depends on your application.

I would not use these for SSD as they are journaling file systems and will cause extra read-write cycles to your drive.

All formatted drives are reduced capacity due to boot sector, bad sectors (in the case of faulty drives), and other system/OS allocation.

As far as compatibility, [Ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) can only be read by linux systems, whereas [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) can be read by both.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with extra writes to SSDs.  Nothing.

Comment: "It is a well-known fact that SSDs have a limited number of write/erase cycles. While this limit is far beyond any usage level a regular user might encounter, some still prefer to take extra cautionary measures." http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/whitepaper/whitepaper12.html

Comment: How do Mac users possibly survive this "limited write cycles" issue… on a journaled format, then?